# Need Guidance on how to copy an existing Repo, rename it and create a new Repo

Tags: git, github

I have an existing repository for Cypress automation for an application .I would like to copy the repo -> rename it -> create a new repo for another application

Comment: Do you want to copy the *repository* (i.e., *all the commits*), or just the *one commit extracted from* the repository? [BigHeadCreations' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69856147/1256452) does the latter.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clone the existing repo that you want to copy. Let's call it Cypress.
2. Duplicate the folder (right click->Duplicate on macOS) and rename it Cypress2.
3. Delete the `.git` folder. Any folder that starts with a period `.` is hidden by default so you will first have to "show hidden files" for your OS.
4. `git init` in the Cypress2 folder.

---

Or you can do the above on the command line like this:

1. `git clone ...` to your Downloads folder
2. `cp -R ~/Downloads/Cypress ~/Downloads/Cypress2`
3. `rm -R ~/Downloads/Cypress2/.git`
4. `cd ~/Downloads/Cypress2`
5. `git init`

Comment: No problem. You can select the answer as correct.